# How to get a part of a substring from a particular string in python

Tags: string, python-2.7, substring

I have a string

```
str = <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/jc8zayasOB8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and I want to take the substring in src - ie 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/jc8zayasOB8'. So how can we achieve this.
 I tried this

```
 my_string="hello python world , i'm a beginner "
 print my_string.split("world",1)[1] .
```

But it gives all string after world . I want only the substring inside src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
string = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/jc8zayasOB8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
start_src = string.find('src="')
first_quote = string.find('"', start_src)
end_quote = string.find('"', first_quote+1)

print string[first_quote+1:end_quote]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear friend